# Prevent default behavior of AuditingEntityListener in specific cases

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I use AuditingEntityListener and annotations @*CreatedDate* and @*LastModifiedDate* to manage creation/modification dates:

```
//...
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;
//...

@Column(name = "creation_time", nullable = false)
@CreatedDate
private LocalDateTime creationDate;

@Column(name = "modification_time", nullable = false)
@LastModifiedDate
private LocalDateTime modificationDate;
```

However, sometimes I want to be able to modify this entity without creationDate and modificationDate fields being modified as well. Is there a way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use correspond column properties:

```
@Column(name = "creation_time", nullable = false, updatable = false)
@CreatedDate
private LocalDateTime creationDate;

@Column(name = "modification_time", nullable = false, insertable = false)
@LastModifiedDate
private LocalDateTime modificationDate;
```

I think your issue was not with `AuditingEntityListener`.

---

If you interesting manage in your own way `modificationDate` you should not use `@LastModifiedDate` annotation near `modificationDate` field and implement your special rules for simple field:

```
@Column(name = "modification_time", nullable = false)
private LocalDateTime modificationDate;
```